# WinAPI - CreateFile fails, invalid path for Bluetooth LE service

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a little program that enumerates BLE devices and their services.
Using *SetupDiGetDeviceProperty* I was able to get the child services of those BLE devices, or rather their device instance paths, like this one here:

*BTHLEDevice{00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_dbc664e1783f\9&1b8d685b&c&0008*

Now, how do I use this path with *CreateFile*? I tried putting "\\?\" at the beginning but that doesn't work, *CreateFile* fails and *GetLastError* returns 3, which indicates that the specified path doesn't exist.

```
HANDLE handle = CreateFile(L"\\\\?\\BTHLEDevice{00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_dbc664e1783f\\9&1b8d685b&c&0008",
                        GENERIC_WRITE    | GENERIC_READ,
                        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
                        NULL,
                        OPEN_EXISTING,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) printf("Error: 0x%X\n", GetLastError());
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you want to see. The ammount of code is rather large.

Comment: A single call to `CreateFile` is easy enough. You won't have any trouble creating a short example that demonstrates the problem. If you want help you'll do that and supply an MCVE.

Comment: Okay, I added the snippet in the orginal post

Comment: And why do you feel that `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` should not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the paths given by *DEVPKEY_Device_Children* aren't usable with CreateFile.
I was able to verify that by enumerating all interfaces by GUID and outputting their paths. Problem solved.

Comment: So have you managed to create a handle to the BLE devices? If so, how did you do that?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, it's been quite a long while, but take a look at 'SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail', I used it to extract the path of the interface.